# eclipselink condition on class type in ReportQuery

Tags: java, eclipselink

Assume I have two entities ChildClassA e ChildClassB that inherits from class MySuperClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TAB")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "MY_DISC")
public class MySuperClass 
{
    @Column
    private String X;   
    @Column
    private String Y;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "A")
public class ChildClassA extends MySuperClass 
{
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
public class ChildClassB extends MySuperClass 
{
    ...
}
```

I also have another class OtherClass with a property myclass of type MySuperClass:

```
@Entity
public class OtherClass
{   
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    private MySuperClass myclass;
    ...
}
```

I want to make a query on the entity OtherClass, in the where clause i need a condition like instanceof to apply on the property myclass. 
Something like this:

```
ExpressionBuilder ebQuery = new ExpressionBuilder();
ReportQuery rQuery = new ReportQuery(OtherClass.class, ebQuery);

Expression exp =     ebQuery.get("X").equal("my value x")
        .and(ebQuery.get("Y").equal("my value y"))
        .and(ebQuery.get("myClass").instanceOf(ChildClassA.class));

rQuery.setSelectionCriteria(exp);

ExecuteQuery(ebQuery);
```

Is there a way to do **ebQuery.get("mySuperClass").instanceOf(ChildClassA.class)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `type()`:

```
ebQuery.get("myClass").type().equal(ChildClassA.class)
```